# problem with launching whatsapp to send a message with flutter url_launcher

Tags: flutter, whatsapp, url-launcher

this is the function to send an WhatsApp message (or just launch the WhatsApp with the message)

in the Cipher.dart

```
void sendCodeByWhatsApp(
       String phone,
      String message,
      ) async {
    String url() {
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        return "https://wa.me/$phone/?text=$message";
      } else {
        return "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$phone=$message";
      }
    }
    if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(url()))) {
      await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url()));
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch ${url()}';
    }
  }
```

and here I use it:

```
 ElevatedButton(
                         child: const Icon(Icons.whatsapp, color: Colors.white,),
                         onPressed: (){
                             Cipher().sendCodeByWhatsApp(encrypt.encrypt, phone.text);
                         },
                       ),
```

when adding a number and message, just open a page with WhatsApp logo, tells me:

```
we couldn't find the page you were looking for
```

Comment: Is it a valid phone number?

Comment: why you add url function inside sendCodeByWhatsApp function?

Comment: on ios or android?

Comment: yes, valid number, and it is Android

Comment: did you add the country code to the phone number with double 00 leading (for example 00666xxxxxxxxx)?

Comment: What does ``print("https://wa.me/$phone/?text=$message")`` log in console?

Comment: @OMiShah
https://wa.me/9687710498004?text=mjqqt%25
print correctly my number and my message

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this to get how to use the link properly [link](https://faq.whatsapp.com/452366545421244/)

There may also be an error if the number includes the country code like

> +1 0123456789

Will give an error. The phone should not include the country code.

Comment: I tried , but still same issue

Answer (score 0):

after doing some search, finally found the solution:

same code above, but the URL should be like this:

```
 "whatsapp://send?phone=$phone&text=${Uri.parse(message)}";
```

for android, and it is working like a charm...

Comment: `https://wa.me/$phone?text=$message` would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change the ? to & and it will open the WhatsApp page in the browser for you

```
"https://wa.me/$phone/&text=$message";
```